# Getting headers and status code while using fetch_feed

Tags: feed

I am using fetch_feed to pull in an rss feed, however I'd like to get the feeds header and the status code in the results.

Is there a method to modify the results to include these two items(status code, headers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fetch_feed() returns a SimplePie object. From a quick glance at [its source](https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie/blob/master/src/SimplePie.php), it looks like you can use

```php
$feed->status_code     // on the public API
$feed->data['headers'] // technically private
```

Comment: ps: might also try these public methods `$feed->status_code()` and `$feed->get_raw_data()['headers']`

Comment: It doesn't appear that status_code is accessible in wordpress' implementation of SimplePie. The headers one worked though.

Comment: birgire is right: in WordPress's one it should be a function ->status_code() https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.2.2/wp-includes/class-simplepie.php#L1837